# Resetting range variable in VBA loop causes 424 error

Tags: vba, excel

So I know I asked a very similar question yesterday, its actually about the same code. Former question can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32887211/range-of-object-global-failed-excel-formatting/)

Its 99% complete, but theres a runtime error in the loop that causes it to fail. What I don't understand is that it runs through once, does everything it needs to, then resetting the range variable YTD causes it to stop at YTD.Formula = YTDs. Code below.

```
    Sub offset(rows1 As Long)
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    'Integers
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    'Movers
    Dim current As Range
    Dim first As Range
    'Metrics
    Dim QTRA As Range
    Dim YTD As Range
    Dim yr1 As Range
    Dim yr3 As Range
    Dim yr7 As Range
    Dim yr5 As Range
    Dim yr10 As Range
    Dim SI As Range
    Dim QTR As Range
    Dim YTD_2 As Range
    Dim yr1_2 As Range
    Dim yr3_2 As Range
    Dim yr5_2 As Range
    Dim yr7_2 As Range
    Dim yr10_2 As Range
    Dim SI_2 As Range
    'Strings
    Dim QTRAs As String
    Dim YTDs As String
    Dim yr1s As String
    Dim yr3s As String
    Dim yr7s As String
    Dim yr5s As String
    Dim yr10s As String
    Dim SIs As String
    Dim QTRs As String
    Dim YTD_2s As String
    Dim yr1_2s As String
    Dim yr3_2s As String
    Dim yr5_2s As String
    Dim yr7_2s As String
    Dim yr10_2s As String
    Dim SI_2s As String

    'Puts in the metric names on the top row. Can be adjusted for 2nd row if need be
    Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("T1").Formula = "YTD"
    Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("U1").Formula = "yr1"
    Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("V1").Formula = "yr3"
    Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("W1").Formula = "yr5"
    Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("Y1").Formula = "yr7"
    Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("X1").Formula = "yr10"
    Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("Z1").Formula = "SI"
    Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("AA1").Formula = "QTR"
    Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("AB1").Formula = "YTD_2"
    Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("AC1").Formula = "yr1"
    Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("AD1").Formula = "yr3"
    Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("AE1").Formula = "yr5"
    Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("AF1").Formula = "yr7"
    Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("AG1").Formula = "yr10"
    Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("AH1").Formula = "SI"

    'Finds the length of the data
    'Dim rn As Range
    'Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Comparative Performance1")
    'Set rn = sh.UsedRange
    'k = rn.Rows.Count + rn.Row - 1
    k = rows1

    For i = 3 To k
        'Setting vari ables for each respective data column
        Set current = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("J" & i)
        Set first = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("B" & i)
        Set QTRA = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("S" & i)
        Set YTD = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("T" & i)
        Set yr1 = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("U" & i)
        Set yr3 = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("V" & i)
        Set yr5 = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("W" & i)
        Set yr7 = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("Y" & i)
        Set yr10 = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("X" & i)
        Set SI = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("Z" & i)
        Set QTR = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("AA" & i)
        Set YTD_2 = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("AB" & i)
        Set yr1_2 = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("AC" & i)
        Set yr3_2 = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("AD" & i)
        Set yr5_2 = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("AE" & i)
        Set yr7_2 = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("AF" & i)
        Set yr10_2 = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("AG" & i)
        Set SI_2 = Sheets("Comparative Performance1").Range("AH" & i)
        'Moves the benchmarks if it is missing a creation date
        If current = "" Then
            Range(first, current).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range(first, current).offset(-1, 9).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            'I have it deleting the entire row, which may remove necessary data, not sure yet
            rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        'First we have to create strings for all of the formulas using the variable i
        YTDs = "=C" + CStr(i) + "-L" + CStr(i)
        yr1s = "=D" + CStr(i) + "-M" + CStr(i)
        yr3s = "=E" + CStr(i) + "-N" + CStr(i)
        yr5s = "=F" + CStr(i) + "-O" + CStr(i)
        yr7s = "=G" + CStr(i) + "-P" + CStr(i)
        yr10s = "=H" + CStr(i) + "-Q" + CStr(i)
        SIs = "=I" + CStr(i) + "-R" + CStr(i)
        QTRs = "=S" + CStr(i) + "/B" + CStr(i)
        YTD_2s = "=S" + CStr(i) + "/B" + CStr(i)
        yr1_2s = "=U" + CStr(i) + "/D" + CStr(i)
        yr3_2s = "=V" + CStr(i) + "/E" + CStr(i)
        yr5_2s = "=W" + CStr(i) + "/F" + CStr(i)
        yr7_2s = "=X" + CStr(i) + "/G" + CStr(i)
        yr10_2s = "=Y" + CStr(i) + "/H" + CStr(i)
        SI_2s = "=Z" + CStr(i) + "/I" + CStr(i)
        'This should assign all of the metrics using the correct variables
        YTD.Formula = YTDs ********** THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS ************
        yr1.Formula = yr1s
        yr3.Formula = yr3s
        yr5.Formula = yr5s
        yr7.Formula = yr7s
        yr10.Formula = yr10s
        SI.Formula = SIs
        QTR.Formula = QTRs
        YTD_2.Formula = YTD_2s
        yr1_2.Formula = yr1_2s
        yr3_2.Formula = yr3_2s
        yr5_2.Formula = yr5_2s
        yr7_2.Formula = yr7_2s
        yr10_2.Formula = yr10_2s
        SI_2.Formula = SI_2s
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You just deleted `Rows(i)` where the range was.

Comment: Can you try deletion in the beginning of the loop? Or decrement i and Continue the iteration

Comment: Your code will be much shorter and easier to debug if you declare a `sht` Worksheet variable and set it to `Sheets("Comparative Performance1")`.  You're also managing a lot of unnecessary variables here: if you declare a variable and only use it *once* then you probably don't need it.  `sht.Range("U" & i).Formula = "=D" + CStr(i) + "-M" + CStr(i)` is easier to manage

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue could be within your `If` statement on the line that says `Rows(i).entirerow.delete`. You are essentially deleting the `Row(i)` along with the range assigned to YTD which is equal to `Range("T"& i )`. You either need to

1. Delete the row before assigning values to your variables
2. Add the following after deleting the row:

   `i=i-1` 'this will re-do the row you deleted

   `Next i` 'This will take you back to the top of the look.
3. Do some error handling that returns you to the top after hitting that error.

Answer (score 0):

You will run into problems if you delete rows within a FOR statement that increments on each pass as you end up with row discrepancies.

The following code may be of use to you...

```
Sub Offset(Optional rows1 As Long)
    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Sheets("Comparative Performance1")

    Dim HeaderRow As Long: HeaderRow = 1
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = sh.Cells.Find("*", _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
    If rows1 > HeaderRow Then LastRow = rows1

    Dim i As Long, k As Long, Counter As Long: Counter = 0

    With sh
        'Puts in the metric names on the top row. Can be adjusted for 2nd row if need be
        Dim Headers() As String: Headers = _
            Split("YTD,yr1,yr3,yr5,yr7,yr10,SI,QTR,YTD_2,yr1,yr3,yr5,yr7,yr10,SI", ",")
        For i = 0 To UBound(Headers)
            .Cells(HeaderRow, 20 + i) = Headers(i) 'Starts at Col T
        Next i

        For i = LastRow To HeaderRow + 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 10).Value = "" Then
                .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 10)).Copy
                .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 10)).Offset(-1, 9).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                Counter = Counter + 1
            End If
        Next i

        For i = HeaderRow + 2 To LastRow - Counter
            For k = 1 To 7 'Metrics on YTD to SI
                .Cells(i, k + 19).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-17]-RC[-8]"
                .Cells(i, k + 27).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]/RC[-25]"
            Next k
            .Cells(i, 27).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-8]/RC[-25]" 'Metric on QTR
        Next i

    End With
End Sub
```

---

Oh - I also assume you have an error with the following line:

```
YTD_2s = "=S" + CStr(i) + "/B" + CStr(i)
```

Where I guess it should actually be:

```
YTD_2s = "=T" + CStr(i) + "/C" + CStr(i)
```

Comment: Good catch on the YTD_2s. As someone who's fairly new to VBA your code is a lot more complicated looking than mine. I am aware that mine is  quite redundant in all of the variable setting, but I'd rather it be slow and work than be fast and make mistakes.

Will your code do exactly what I am trying to do?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see? Essentially it should do what is coded in the question - but it's whether that code is correct for your usage or needs alterations. Without seeing the spreadsheet I've had to guess at usage. The code itself is split into 3 blocks; the first takes your headers, splits it into an array then pastes each array value into the cells required. The second part parses for missing data and deletes rows that don't conform (If there is an error it is likely to be here). The third just adds in the formulas using relative formulas. It worked for me but you'll need to test it...